# Load a single symbol from a LaTeX package

Tags: latex, package, symbols

When using the MnSymbol package, pdflatex gives two font warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Encoding 'OMS' has changed to 'U' for symbol font
(Font)              'symbols' in the math version 'normal' on input line 120.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font 'symbols' in version 'normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> U/MnSymbolF/m/n on input line 120.
```

It turns out that this is probably due to a clash with the AMSSymb package.

Since I need just a few symbols from the package: is there a way to load one symbol from a package, in stead of all?

Comment: Is there some actual problem with the typesetting, or are you just worried about seeing the warnings?

Comment: I haven't seen any typesetting problems; I'm just trying to keep the number of warnings to a minimum.

Comment: In the mean time I have spotted trouble: the MnSymbol package is changing a number of symbols from amssymb. The documentation states it is not compatible.

Comment: Revisited this issue today. Unfortunately, MnSymbol still changes AMS symbols. The workaround via fakeMnSymbols is a nice workaround, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I solved this:

Download the perl script "makefakeMnSymbol" from the comprehensive latex symbol document source:
http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/source/makefakeMnSymbol

Next, at command line do `chmod +x makefakeMnSymbol` to make it executable.  Then, run

```
./makefakeMnSymbol `kpsewhich MnSymbol.sty` > fakeMnSymbol.sty
```

Put fakeMnSymbol.sty in a texmf directory of choice (global or local), and run `texhash`

If you now put

```
\usepackage{fakeMnSymbol}
```

in your preamble, you can now use any MnSymbol, like `\powerset` by prefixing it like `\MNSpowerset`

Big thanks to Scott Pakin for this hack... and for his comprehensive symbol guide...

---

This hack has problems with symbols in subscripts/superscripts.  A work-around is to use look at the `fakeMnSymbol.sty` source to find which font the symbol you want was loaded from, along with its number.  Here's an example from one of my preambles where I override the built-in `\boxminus` with an MnSymbol:

```
\usepackage[]{fakeMnSymbol}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mnsymbolc}{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
\let\boxminus=\undefined
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boxminus}{2}{mnsymbolc}{112}
```

Answer (score 2):

These warnings are nothing to worry about. In fact, in the next LaTeX release they'll disappear (see the [original bug report](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/3975)). No ETA on that, however.

> Moreover, is there any real chance this affects the typesetting of the document?

Nope.

> is there any way to prevent this?

Can patch the LaTeX warning message code before loading the package, and then restore it again afterwards (this is what I've done in the past in my own packages), but as a user I'd just learn to ignore the warning.

Comment: See also the comments: it does affect the typesetting of the document by replacing a lot of standard AMS symbols.

Comment: Well, of course if you load a package to change the maths font you get different symbols :)

Comment: Obviously. I'll try to find a workaround to load only certain symbols I need (which are \lefthalfsqcup and double braces)

Answer (score 1):

The following might help.  This is the code I had to add in order to get just the \bigominus symbol out of the MnSymbol package.

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolF}{}<br>
\DeclareSymbolFont{mnsymbols}{U}{MnSymbolF}{m}{n}<br>
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolF}{m}{n}{<br>
    <-6>  MnSymbolF5<br>
   <6-7>  MnSymbolF6<br>
   <7-8>  MnSymbolF7<br>
   <8-9>  MnSymbolF8<br>
   <9-10> MnSymbolF9<br>
  <10-12> MnSymbolF10<br>
  <12->   MnSymbolF12}{}<br>
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigominus}{\mathop}{mnsymbols}{55}
```